# flutterdownloader not downloading a file again which is already deleted

Tags: flutter, dart, download, flutter-downloader

```
await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
          url: Uri.parse(url).toString(),
          savedDir: fullPath,
          fileName: actualFileName,
          showNotification: true,
          openFileFromNotification: true,
          saveInPublicStorage: true);
```

When deleting file from the file explorer and download the same file again always failing

In iOS it is working, Issue with android device only.

**Steps:**

1. download a file (FlutterDownloader.enqueue())
2. delete the file manually from downloads
3. download the same file FlutterDownloader.enqueue())

**Console Error:**
D/DownloadWorker(12373): Update notification: {notificationId: 8, title: GOA-1924573-2180476 (2).pdf, status: FAILED, progress: -1}

W/System.err(12373): java.lang.NullPointerException

W/System.err(12373): at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.downloadFile(DownloadWorker.kt:385)

W/System.err(12373): at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.doWork(DownloadWorker.kt:206)

W/System.err(12373): at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:86)

W/System.err(12373): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)

W/System.err(12373): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)

W/System.err(12373): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

I/WM-WorkerWrapper(12373): Worker result FAILURE for Work [ id=4ef9a1d3-ff16-467f-b797-5fb7d3a981b5, tags={ flutter_download_task, vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker } ]

Anyone please help me to resolve this

Note: deleted file name and new download attempt file name same

Comment: put your code here

Comment: await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
          url: Uri.parse(url).toString(),
          savedDir: fullPath,
          fileName: actualFileName,
          showNotification: true,
          openFileFromNotification: true,
          saveInPublicStorage: true);

Comment: in url part you write `url: Uri.parse(url).toString()`, Uri type is different with String so you need to delete `toString()` and it become like this `url: Uri.parse(url)`.

Comment: It will show error because url is String type

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue you are facing with the FlutterDownloader plugin on Android seems related to how the file deletion is handled. When you delete a file and then attempt to download the same file again, the FlutterDownloader might still be referencing the old file path which no longer exists, leading to a NullPointerException.

To resolve this issue, try the following steps

1. Clear Cached File Path
   2.Check File Permissions
2. Update Plugin
3. Debug Log Analysis

Comment: can you please mention how to clear cached file path

Comment: please mention how to clear specified cached file path